# Can a Dirac delta function be a probability density function of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Can the Dirac delta function (or distribution) be a probability density function of a random variable. To my knowledge, it seem to satisfy the conditions. To my interpretation getting a positive real number as the outcome is 1 and that for a negative real number is zero. I wonder what could be the expected value. My question is, whether it is a valid probability density function of a random variable.

Comment: If so, what would you expect the CDF to look like?

Comment: @J.M. : a unit step function.

Comment: @J.M. : I am not getting what you intend to say.

Comment: @Rajesh: The Dirac delta defines a perfectly good probability measure. However, it is not a function!

Comment: @Zhen : even if its not a function, if it makes some logical sense, why should we not construct such a logic. Has it been used anywhere in Probability theory.

Comment: @Rajesh:  As implied in my answer, yes, of course. Modern probability theory allows for distributions which do not have well-defined density *functions*.

Comment: @Zhen : Could we say that such random variables are perfectly random. For example, consider a RV $X$ with $\delta(x)$ as pdf and another RV $Y$ with $p_Y(y)$ as pdf. Now the RV defined as $Z = X + Y$ has the same pdf as that of $Y$. Which intuitively means that $X$ is  perfectly random, yet it does'nt throw any new information which is some what counter intuitive.

Comment: It *is* a function, but not on the space you're used to work with...

Comment: @RajeshD: On the contrary, what you describe means that $X$ is perfectly non-random.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in Gortaur's answer a delta function cannot be the probability density function of a real random variable.

Nevertheless sums of delta functions can be viewed as the "missing link" between discrete and continuous random variables / probability distributions, in the following way:

If $X$ is a discrete random variable taking values $x_k\in{\mathbb R}$ $\ (k\in I$, $\ I$ a countable index set) with probabilities $p_k$ then one can replace the probability space $I$ with the probability space ${\mathbb R}$, provided with the probability measure
$$\mu\ :=\ \sum_{k\in I} p_k \ \delta_{x_k}\ ,$$
where $\delta_x$ denotes a unit point mass at the point $x$. In this way $X$ now has become a real random variable. If $f:\ {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ is a reasonable function then the expectation $E\bigl(f(X)\bigr)$ may be written as an integral:
$$E\bigl(f(X)\bigr)\ =\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ d\mu(x)\ .$$

Comment: Gortaur's answer does not exist. Could you update the answer with the relevant content in the original answer?

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia article on PDF [implies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Link_between_discrete_and_continuous_distributions) that $\delta(x)$ can be used as a generalized PDF. The corresponding CDF would be the Heaviside (unit step) function as already mentioned. Expected value is 0; I would not really call that variable "random".

Comment: "Expected value is 0; I would not really call that variable "random"." - that's what I was sort of getting at in the comments; I guess I was too oblique... :D

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, pdf of a random variable $X$ w.r.t Lebesgue measure $\mu$ is defined $\mu$-a.e. as a solution of
$$
\mathsf P\{X\in A\} = \int\limits_Af(x)\mu(dx)
$$
for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$
where the last integral is Lebesgue integral. For sure you can talk about an integration using $\delta$ function, but usually I mention that people distinguish *distributions with densities* only when talking about absolute continuous distributions. The distribution of $X\equiv0$ is not absolute continuous since $\mathsf P\{X\in \{0\} \} = 1$ while $\mu(\{0\}) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

> Can the Dirac delta function (or distribution) be a probability density function of a random variable. To my knowledge, it seem to satisfy the conditions.

That depends on your definition. If you insist that you use the Lesbegue measure as a reference measure, then the delta function is not a Radon-Nikodym density with respect to this reference measure. But if you choose a different reference measure like the counting measure, which assigns to every set the number of its elements, then the delta function is a density (it is the characteristic function of the set {0}).

> To my interpretation getting a positive real number as the outcome is 1 and that for a negative real number is zero.

No, the probability to get the number zero is 1, the probability to get anything else is zero.

> I wonder what could be the expected value.

Since this random variable is 0 with probability 1, the expected value is 0.

Comment: How could one convince himself that the probability of getting the number 0 is 1.

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} \delta(x) dx$ is $1$ if $a=0$, and $0$ if $a\neq 0$.

Comment: That proves that the probability of getting the number 0 is 1, and the probability of getting any other number is 0. Which is what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about linear transformation of a zero mean gaussian random variable X. Defining random variable Y=aX, one can easily shows that the probability density function of Y is: $$ p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{|a|}.p_X(y/a)$$ It can be showed that as "a" tends to zero, the $$ p_Y(y)\to\delta (y)$$ Therefore, in my opinion, Dirac delta function can be used to describe the PDF of such a random variable.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for the answer

Comment: a tends to zero or infty? You may want a to go to zero in your answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. tend to zero.