# find joint distribution $\min (X,Y)$ and $W$, where W is a discrete distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, order-statistics

> Let, $X,Y$ are independent rv with pdf.s
>
> $f_X(x\mid \lambda)=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}$, $x>0$ and $f_Y(y\mid \mu)=\dfrac{1}{\mu}e^{-x/\mu}$, $y>0$.
>
> Let $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$ and
>
> $W=1$ if $Z=X$ and $0$ if $Z=Y$
>
> Find joint distribution of $(Z,W)$?

I found pmf of $W$ which is $f_W(w)=\Big(\dfrac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\Big)^w\Big(\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\Big)^{1-w}$

But have problem while calculating $P(Z\leq z, W=1)$.

$P(Z\leq z, W=1)=P(Z\leq z\mid W=1)P(W=1)=P(X\leq z)P(W=1)$

The last line does not look right to me. What should I do? Thanks for any help!

Comment: $\Pr (Z \le z, W=1) = \Pr (X\le z, X \le Y)$

Answer (score -1):

First, develop joint distribution of $W$ and $Z$ for both $W$ cases:

$$\begin{align}f(Z=z,W=0)&=f(Z=z,Z=Y)\\&=f(Y=z,Y<X)\\&=f(Y=z,X>z)\\&=f(Y=z)~P(X>z)\\[2ex]f(Z=z,W=1)&=f(Z=z,Z=X)\\&=f(X=z,X<Y)\\&=f(X=z,Y>z)\\&=f(X=z)~P(Y>z)\end{align}$$

Last two terms can be written as follow:

$$\begin{align}f(Z=z,W=0) &= f(Y=z)~P(X>z) \\&= \frac{1}{\mu}e^{-z/\mu} e^{-z/\lambda}\\[2ex]f(Z=z,W=1) &= f(X=z)~P(Y>z) \\&= \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-z/\lambda} e^{-z/\mu}\end{align}$$

Finally, one can write:
$$\begin{align}f(Z=z,W=w)&=e^{\raise{1ex}{-\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu} \right)z}}~\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^w\left(\frac{1}{\mu}\right)^{1-w}\end{align}$$

Comment: Is that it? Actually I did almost same thing. But problem I am getting is that if that's the answer, can we get $f_Z(z)=P(Z=z, W=0)+P(Z=z, W=1)$? I am totally confused.

Comment: here, $f_Z(z)=\Big(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}+\dfrac{1}{\mu}\Big)e^{-(z/\lambda+z/\mu)}$ is pdf of $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I think I found the error. Let me correct the answer

Comment: Every event involving $X=z$ or $Y=z$ has probability zero, thus none of the computations in this post is legit, I am afraid.

Comment: I will change P by f to make it clear that it is a pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW this might not be big deal, but if you write $f$, it makes a big problem (since in your solution $f$ might stand for pdf, but it complicates the part $W$ is a discrete rv.) To avoid such confusion, (learnt from my experience), you might try to find $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{P\Big(x-\dfrac{h}{2}< Z\leq x+\dfrac{h}{2}, W=1\Big)}{h}$$

Comment: Yes, I see your point. So, how would you write the joint distribution of a continuous RV and a discrete RV? I don't know what notation would be right

Comment: "I will change P by f to make it clear that it is a pdf" But "it" is **NOT** a PDF.

Comment: @Did, is for you $f(Z=z,W=w) = e^{-z \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu} \right)} \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} \delta(w-1) + \frac{1}{\mu} \delta(w) \right)$ a pdf? For me, it is. Not differentiable, but it is a pdf

Comment: @CarlosCampos Of course not, please review the definition of the PDF of a random variable. The trouble with your suggestion is not even that the RHS is not differentiable, but that it is not a function.

Comment: Wow @Did, Is it not a function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\} \rightarrow [0,1]$ ? I am getting lost...

Comment: Hmmm... how to break this mental blockage? Maybe simply recall what D and F mean in PDF?

Comment: Other people share my point of view: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54197/can-a-dirac-delta-function-be-a-probability-density-function-of-a-random-variabl

Comment: That you think the link you provide shows what you say is stunning. Did you read the page you link to? (Unrelated: Please use @, that is, unless you want the users you address your comments to, to be made aware of your comments.)

Comment: @Did, I was referring to this particular link which appears in that page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Link_between_discrete_and_continuous_distributions
It is a different way to consider probability distributions of discrete variables. Link between continuous and discrete variables.  It makes sense for me.sense for me

Comment: Right, I had missed this paragraph. Mathematically, this is horrible. I know that some physicists like to consider discrete measures as functions, but for which practical advantages? And if we turn to pedagogy, the effects are disastrous...

Comment: @Did, For me, using this notation eases the way to express joint probability distributions of discrete and contineous variables (i.e. $f(X=x,W=w)$. Maybe, the only other alternative would be to express $P(X<x,W=w)$, which avoids the use of Dirac artifact, but taking the cdf over X

Comment: That, but rather as $P(X\leqslant x,W=w)$. Or, for a completely rigorous way of writing down the joint distribution of $(X,W)$ when the distribution of $X$ is purely absolutely continuous and the distribution of $W$ is purely discrete, $$P_{(X,W)}(dxdw)=\sum_kf_k(x)\delta_{w_k}(dw)dx$$

Comment: Yes @Did, I strongly agree. Coming back to the original question, could $f(Z=z,W=w) = e^{-z \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu} \right)} \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} \delta(w-1) + \frac{1}{\mu} \delta(w) \right)$ be the right answer?

Comment: Sorry but, as already explained, one cannot reasonably declare that a formula involving the horror $$f(Z=z,W=w)$$ is "correct"... But if your question is whether the formula $$P_{(Z,W)}(dzdw)=e^{-\lambda^{-1}z-\mu^{-1}z}(\lambda^{-1}\delta_1(dw)+\mu^{-1}\delta_0(dw))dz$$ is correct, then the answer is yes.